# idea for starting Inventory management app with django

Tags: python, django, inventory

I want to create a simple inventory management app with django which user can add item in inventory and also exit item as much as he want and then we must can take a report from number of  existing items in inventory

any idea that how should i start?

Comment: This is usually not the kind of question stackoverflow encourages, Start by learning django

Comment: You should start by getting a Django project going and writing some code.

Comment: until now i create a model for items and a models for ordered items(exited item)
but i want to make a report of existing items in inventory
how should i do that by subtracting added item by exited item?

Answer (score 0):

My solution (i don't use Oscar) Is to add stock for each variation. And update accordingly in post-save/pre-save orders. If you dont use variation then add it to the product model.

Bear in mind following conditions to update the stock:

When order is placed first time.
When quantity is changed in order (get the difference).
When order is cancelled first time.